# Upload de imagem com JS

Tags: php, javascript, html, upload

Boa tarde,
Estou tentando fazer o upload de imagem usando JS mas não estou conseguindo, não estou usando jQuery, estou usando o Axios.

Ate agora, tentei dessa maneira

```
var files = document.getElementById("inputPhoto").files;

axios.post(url+'api.php', {
        file: new FormData(imagem])
    }, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    })
    .then(function(response){
        console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error)
    })
```

OBS: estou usando o multiple do HTML5, o BackEnd já esta pronto em PHP

Comment: Tens um erro de sintaxe aqui `new FormData(imagem])` e essa variável não está no código da pergunta... Algum erro na consola?

Comment: na verdade a imagem é a variavel files, foi erro meu na hora de escrever aqui, mas o codigo esta certo

Comment: Já testaste da maneira "oficial" https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/blob/master/examples/upload/index.html#L25-L35 ?

Comment: @Sergio vou tentar, porem ai é um exemplo para se trabalhar com uma foto por vez, queria com varias, usando o multiple

Comment: @Sergio dessa forma funcionou, mas ainda só consigo recuperar uma imagem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo [sugestões do repositorio no Github](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/blob/master/examples/upload/index.html), podes simplesmente ir adicioando ao FormData:

```js
var files = document.getElementById("inputPhoto").files;
let data = new FormData();

for (var i = 0, l = files.length; i < l; i++) {
  let file = files.item(i);
  data.append('images[' + i + ']', file, file.name);
}

const config = {
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
}

axios.post('/api/images', data, config);
```